# Critical points of a function and system of equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I'm reading DoCarmo's *Differential Geometry of Surfaces and Curves*, and there is an exercise I can't resolve.

> Let $f(x,y,z)=(x+y+z-1)^2$. Locate the critical points of $f$ and critical values of $f$.

I have to calculate de partial derivates of $f$ and then find where they vanishes. So $f_x=f_y=f_z=2(x+y+z-1)$ and then I need to resolve the equation $x+y+z-1=0$ and I can't go much further.

Comment: Is the plane where the function is 0

Comment: ie, has a min in this plane

Comment: We have from linear algebra, that $x+y+z=1$ implies this parametric equations, $x=1-s-t$, $y=s$ and $z=t$, where $s,t$ are real numbers. I hope that you, or another user can provide a full answer. Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, according to the definition 2 of Chapter 2 (p.58) a critical point of a differentiable map is the point where its *differential* is not surjective.

**Second**, according to Appendix B to the Chapter 2 differential of a map is, in fact, its *Jacobian Matrix* (p. 128).
In your case Jacobian Matrix is simply row vector comprised of partial derivatives of $\,f\,$:
$$
\mathrm{d}\,f\left(x,\,y,\,z\right) = 
\begin{bmatrix} f_x & f_y & f_z \end{bmatrix} =
2\big(x+y+z-1\big) \cdot\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

**Third**, the last paragraph before Proposition 2 on page 59 explicitly states that

> $\quad\left(\;\ldots\;\right)\quad\mathrm{d}\,f_p\,$ is not surjective is equivalent to saying that $\,f_x=f_y =f_z=0\,$ at $\,p$.

Therefore we conclude that in your case critical point is *any* point $\,\big(x,\,y,\,z\big)\,$ satisfying equations $\,x+y+z-1 = 0\,$.
In other words, you have a whole *set of critical points*, which is a plane defined by equation $\,x+y+z = 1\,$.

Comment: And how can I find a basis for the plane?

Comment: When you put $s=1, t=0$ in previous parametric equations obtain the first linear independent vector of such basis, and with $s=0, t=1$ the second @LuisVictoria